# I need some help running a C# menu for customers

Tags: c#, menu

I have completed most of my project but I need help calling a function. On line 38 where it says DisplayCustomerMenu(customer);, I failed to call out the function. What is the correct way to call out this function?

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.IO; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks; 

namespace LabMenu {
public static class Program
{
    public static PreferredCustomer[] preferredCustomers;
    public static Customer customer;



    public static string firstName { get; set; }
    public static string lastName { get; set; }
    public static double flashlight { get; private set; }
    public static double iphone { get; private set; }
    public static double printer { get; private set; }
    public static double laptop { get; private set; }
    public static double playstation { get; private set; }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DisplayMainMenu();
    }

    public static void DisplayMainMenu()
    {
        do
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Menu!");
            Console.WriteLine("0. Quit");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Make An Order");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Manage Customers");

            switch (ConsoleHelper.ReadInt32(0, 1))
            {
                case 0: return;
                case 1: DisplayCustomersMenu(); break;
            };

        } while (true);
    }

    public static void DisplayCustomersMenu()
    {
        do
        {
            Console.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("Make An Order");

            Console.WriteLine($"What is your first name?");
            firstName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine($"What is your last name?");
            lastName = Console.ReadLine();

            string strTarget = String.Format("Hello, {0} {1}.", firstName, lastName);

            Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{0}",
                              Environment.NewLine, strTarget);

            Console.WriteLine("1) Select Customer");
            Console.WriteLine("0) Return to Manage Customers");

            switch (ConsoleHelper.ReadInt32(0, 3))
            {
                case 0: return;
                case 1:
                    {
                        string enteredID = "";

                        do
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Enter the customer ID: ");
                            enteredID = Console.ReadLine();

                            //var id = ConsoleHelper.ReadInt32("Invalid customer ID", 0, Int32.MaxValue);

                            foreach (var id in preferredCustomers)
                            {
                                if (id.CustomerID == enteredID)
                                {
                                    DisplayCustomerMenu(customer); //Is this correct?
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("You are not in the database");
                                }
                            }
                        } while (true);




                        //var customer = SelectCustomer();
                        //if (customer != null)
                        //    DisplayCustomerMenu(customer);
                        //else
                        //    Console.WriteLine("Customer not found");

                        //break;
                    };
            };
        } while (true);
    }


    public static void DisplayCustomerMenu(Customer customer)
    {
        do
        {
            Console.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("Manage Customers");

            Console.WriteLine($"Custumer name, ID and current order");


            Console.WriteLine("1) Add to Order");
            Console.WriteLine("2) Remove from Order");
            Console.WriteLine("3) Finalize Order");
            Console.WriteLine("0) Return to Manage Customers");

            switch (ConsoleHelper.ReadInt32(0, 3))
            {
                case 0: return;
                case 1: AddToOrder(customer); break;
                case 2: RemoveFromOrder(customer); break;
                case 3: FinalizeOrder(customer); break;
            };
        } while (true);
    }


    public static void AddToOrder(Customer id)
    {
            Console.Clear();

            int numberOfInputForFlashlight = 0;
            int numberOfInputForIphone = 0;
            int numberOfInputForPrinter = 0;
            int numberOfInputForLaptop = 0;
            int numberOfInputForPlaystation = 0;

            int myint = -1;

        while (myint != 0)
        {
            string group;

            Console.WriteLine("Add To Order");
            Console.WriteLine("1) Flashlight");
            Console.WriteLine("2) iPhone 7");
            Console.WriteLine("3) Printer");
            Console.WriteLine("4) Dell Laptop");
            Console.WriteLine("5) Playstation 4");
            Console.WriteLine("6) View Total");

            Console.WriteLine("[Press 0 to quit]");

            group = Console.ReadLine();
            myint = Int32.Parse(group);

            switch (myint)
            {
                case 0:
                    break;
                case 1:
                    double input1;
                    string inputString1;
                    Console.WriteLine("How many flashlights do you want?");
                    inputString1 = Console.ReadLine();
                    input1 = Convert.ToDouble(inputString1);
                    flashlight += input1;
                    numberOfInputForFlashlight++;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    double input2;
                    string inputString2;
                    Console.WriteLine("How many iPhone 7 do you want?");
                    inputString2 = Console.ReadLine();
                    input2 = Convert.ToDouble(inputString2);
                    iphone += input2;
                    numberOfInputForIphone++;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    double input3;
                    string inputString3;
                    Console.WriteLine("How many Printers do you want?");
                    inputString3 = Console.ReadLine();
                    input3 = Convert.ToDouble(inputString3);
                    printer += input3;
                    numberOfInputForPrinter++;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    double input4;
                    string inputString4;
                    Console.WriteLine("How many Dell Laptops do you want?");
                    inputString4 = Console.ReadLine();
                    input4 = Convert.ToDouble(inputString4);
                    laptop += input4;
                    numberOfInputForLaptop++;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    double input5;
                    string inputString5;
                    Console.WriteLine("How many Playstion 4 do you want?");
                    inputString5 = Console.ReadLine();
                    input5 = Convert.ToDouble(inputString5);
                    playstation += input5;
                    numberOfInputForPlaystation++;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    Console.WriteLine("Flashlist quantity is {0}", flashlight.ToString("F"));
                    Console.WriteLine("iPhone 7 quantity is {0}", iphone.ToString("F"));
                    Console.WriteLine("Printer quantity is {0}", printer.ToString("F"));
                    Console.WriteLine("Dell Laptop quantity is {0}", laptop.ToString("F"));
                    Console.WriteLine("Playstation 4 quantity is {0}", playstation.ToString("F"));
                    Console.WriteLine("Flashlight total is {0}", (flashlight * 15.00).ToString("C"));
                    Console.WriteLine("iPhone 7 total is {0}", (iphone * 700.00).ToString("C"));
                    Console.WriteLine("Printer total is {0}", (printer * 80.00).ToString("C"));
                    Console.WriteLine("Dell Laptop total is {0}", (laptop * 500.00).ToString("C"));
                    Console.WriteLine("Playstation 4 total is {0}", (playstation * 380.00).ToString("C"));
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect input", myint);
                    break;
            }
        }

    }

    public static void FinalizeOrder(Customer customer)
    {
        do
        {
            Console.Clear();
        } while (true);
    }

    static void RemoveFromOrder(Customer customer)
    {
        do
        {
            Console.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("Remove From Order:");
            Console.WriteLine("1) Flashlight total is {0}", (flashlight * 15.00).ToString("C"));
            Console.WriteLine("2) iPhone 7 total is {0}", (iphone * 700.00).ToString("C"));
            Console.WriteLine("3) Printer total is {0}", (printer * 80.00).ToString("C"));
            Console.WriteLine("4) Dell Laptop total is {0}", (laptop * 500.00).ToString("C"));
            Console.WriteLine("5) Playstation 4 total is {0}", (playstation * 380.00).ToString("C"));

            switch (ConsoleHelper.ReadInt32(0, 5))
            {
                case 0: break;
                case 1:
                    double input1;
                    string inputString1;
                    Console.WriteLine("How many flashlights do you want to remove?");
                    inputString1 = Console.ReadLine();
                    input1 = Convert.ToDouble(inputString1);
                    flashlight -= input1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    double input2;
                    string inputString2;
                    Console.WriteLine("How many iPhone 7 do you remove?");
                    inputString2 = Console.ReadLine();
                    input2 = Convert.ToDouble(inputString2);
                    iphone -= input2;
                    break;

                case 3:
                    double input3;
                    string inputString3;
                    Console.WriteLine("How many Printers do you remove?");
                    inputString3 = Console.ReadLine();
                    input3 = Convert.ToDouble(inputString3);
                    printer -= input3;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    double input4;
                    string inputString4;
                    Console.WriteLine("How many Dell Laptops do you remove?");
                    inputString4 = Console.ReadLine();
                    input4 = Convert.ToDouble(inputString4);
                    laptop += input4;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    double input5;
                    string inputString5;
                    Console.WriteLine("How many Playstion 4 do you remove?");
                    inputString5 = Console.ReadLine();
                    input5 = Convert.ToDouble(inputString5);
                    playstation += input5;
                    break;

            };

        } while (true);
    }

    public static void GetData()
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader("CustomerInfo.txt"))
        {
            var index = 0;
            preferredCustomers = new PreferredCustomer[5];
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine().Split(':');
                var name = line[0];
                var address = line[1];
                var phone = line[2];
                var id = line[3];
                var email = line[4];
                var spentAmount = Convert.ToInt32(line[5]);
                var onEmailList = Convert.ToBoolean(line[6]);
                preferredCustomers[index] = new PreferredCustomer(name, address, phone, id, email, spentAmount,
                    onEmailList);
                index++;
            }
        }
    }


    public static void UpdateData()
    {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter("CustomerInfo2.txt"))
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                var name = preferredCustomers[i].CustomerName;
                var address = preferredCustomers[i].Address;
                var phone = preferredCustomers[i].Phone;
                var id = preferredCustomers[i].CustomerID;
                var email = preferredCustomers[i].CustomerID;
                var updatedSpentAmount = preferredCustomers[i].CalcAmount();
                var onEmailList = preferredCustomers[i].OnEmailList;
                writer.WriteLine("{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}:{4}:{5}:{6}",
                name, address, phone, id, email, updatedSpentAmount, onEmailList == true ? "true" : "false");
            }
        }
    }

    public static string UserChoice()
    {
        var userChoice = Console.ReadLine();
        while (userChoice !="1" && userChoice != "2")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong Entry. Try Again.");
            DisplayMenu();
            userChoice = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        return userChoice;
    }

    public static void DisplayMenu()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1. Display Customer Info");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Update Customer Info");
        Console.Write("Please enter your choice: ");
    }

    }
}
```

Also here is 'Customer.cs'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LabMenu
{
public class Customer : Person
{
    public Customer(string name, string address, string phone, string id, string email, int spentAmount,
        bool onEmailList)
        : base(name, address, phone)
    {
        CustomerID = id;
        CustomerEmail = email;
        SpentAmount = spentAmount;
        OnEmailList = onEmailList;
    }

    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }
    public int SpentAmount { get; set; }
    public bool OnEmailList { get; set; }

    public virtual double CalcAmount()
    {
        return SpentAmount;
    }
    }
}
```

Person.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LabMenu
{
    public class Person
{
    public Person(string name, string address, string phone)
    {
        CustomerName = name;
        Address = address;
        Phone = phone;
    }
```

PreferredCustomers.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LabMenu
{
    public class PreferredCustomer : Customer
{
    public PreferredCustomer(string name, string address, string phone, string id,
        string email, int spentAmount, bool onEmailList)
        : base (name, address, phone, id, email, spentAmount, onEmailList)
    {
        DiscountLevel = SetDiscountLevel();
    }

    public readonly decimal DiscountLevel;

    public decimal SetDiscountLevel()
    {
        int range = SpentAmount / 500;
        switch (range)
        {
            case 0:
                return 0;

            case 1:
                return 0.05m;

            case 2:
                return 0.05m;

            case 3:
                return 0.08m;

            default:
                return 0.1m;


        }
    }

    public double GetDiscount()
    {
        return SpentAmount * (double)DiscountLevel;
    }

    public override double CalcAmount()
    {
        return base.CalcAmount() - GetDiscount();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return
            String.Format(
                "CustomerID: {0}\nCustomer Name: {1}\nCustomerAddress: {2}\n" +
                "Customer Phone: {3} \nCustomer Email: {4}" +
                "Customer Spending: {5:C2}\nCustomer On Email List: {6}",
                CustomerID, CustomerName, Address, Phone, CustomerEmail, SpentAmount, OnEmailList
                );
    }

    }
}

    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    }
}
```

CustomerInfo.txt

```
John Candy:123 10th st, Allen, TX  78714:972-555-0000:A0000001:email@gmail.com:2500:true
Robert Smith:456 15th st, Austin, TX 78504:512-456-1000:A0000002:bobsmith@gmail.com:2500:true
Bill Clinton:2004 44th st, Washington, DC 20001:202-456-2222:A0000003:williamc@gmail.com:495:false
Patricia Garner:123 16th st, Washington, DC 20002:202-555-6666:A0000004:garnerp@gmail.com:1200:true
Pablo Corbin:777 2th st, Houston, TX 77002:832-100-2000:A0000005:pcorzbin@yahoo.com:1750:false
```

Comment: You need to pass the variable _id_ if this variable is of type _Customer_

Comment: Ok, if im correct you mean to use id instead of Customer. I have tried that but it did not work.

Comment: I posted my full work if you want to check it out, I am not really sure how to pass it through.

Comment: That is *way* more code than needed for your problem.  Please don't dump your entire program into the question - create a [MCVE] instead.

Comment: It is actually getting to that line is it? Because I can't see where it is populating _preferredCustomers_;it is not calling GetData() anywhere.

Comment: I noticed I was not calling out GetData() and now I have another problem. It simply just crashes. I don't know if I will find out a solution now.

Comment: you should consider writing a new question that more clearly and concisely asks what you want to know.  don't just throw your whole project on here.  Identify the first problem you would like to solve, describe in detail everything you know about the problem (what you want to happen, what is happenning instead, where its happening, etc.), describe some things you have tried, include only the most relevant code to that problem.  Once you have figured that problem, move to the next.